# How to select date range

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a date range in mysql database which is **2016-11-11 - 2016-11-15**
how to select the date that work with any way between the date range ?

So far, the code only work with :

**11-12, 11-13, 11-14, 11-15 , 12-15, 13-15, 14-15, 15-15**

My goal is to make it work with like list below :

**12-11, 12-12, 12-13, 12-14**

**13-11, 13-12, 13-13, 13-14**

**14-11, 14-12, 14-13, 14-14**

Is it possible ?

Here's my SQL statement so far. Appreciate if someone can help me to solve this problem.

```
<?php
    $connect      = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
    global $connect;   

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
        $user_id        = $_POST['user_id'];
        $dtfrom_user    = $_POST['date_from'];
        $dtto_user      = $_POST['date_to'];

        $sql            = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."' 

                                                AND 

                                                   date_from BETWEEN CAST('".$date_from."' AS DATE) AND CAST('".$date_to."'   AS DATE) 
                                                OR 
                                                   date_to   BETWEEN CAST('".$date_from."' AS DATE) AND CAST('".$date_to."'   AS DATE)

                                                AND 

                                                   date_to   BETWEEN CAST('".$date_to."'   AS DATE) AND CAST('".$date_from."' AS DATE) 
                                                OR 
                                                   date_from BETWEEN CAST('".$date_to."'   AS DATE) AND CAST('".$date_from."' AS DATE)
                          ";                                

        $run            = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        if($run && mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0 )
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
            {

            }
            echo "Cannot add date";
        mysqli_free_result($run);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Date added";
            echo mysqli_error($connect);
        }
    }
?>
<form action="date.php" method="post">  
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>User ID : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="user_id" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Date from : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="date_from" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> </td>
            <td>Date to : </td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="date_to" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

    <p><input class="btnSuccess" type ="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> </p>              
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this. `(date_from BETWEEN CAST('".$date_from."' AS DATE) AND CAST('".$date_to."' AS DATE) 
OR date_to BETWEEN CAST('".$date_from."' AS DATE) AND CAST('".$date_to."' AS DATE) )
AND (date_to   BETWEEN CAST('".$date_to."'   AS DATE) AND CAST('".$date_from."' AS DATE) 
OR date_from  BETWEEN CAST('".$date_to."'   AS DATE) AND CAST('".$date_from."' AS DATE))`

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac - Why should he try that? An explanation would be nice.

Comment: sorry, it's not working so far.

Comment: it is to separate the conditions. his code is like `date_from OR date_to AND date_to OR date_from` I just want to try if to separate it to be something like `(date_from OR date_to) AND (date_to OR date_from)`

Comment: @Jamilah provide some sample data which you are getting and the expected result which you require.

Comment: The reason is because the request from the user. They want the system prevent the user to enter 1. same date_from & date_to date, 2. one of the date is in between the range , and 3. Both date_from & date_to is inside date range . :)